# GPG Suite remember password indefinitely

Tags: macos, passwords, keychain, gnupg, gpg-agent

I'm using [GPG Suite](https://gpgtools.org/) with macOS Monterey, in order to save a GPG key's password, so that I can make verified git commits.

**Problem:**
Currently every time I make a verified commit (git commit -S -m "Commit message") for the first time every day, I am being prompted to enter my GPG key's password.

**Desire:**
Ideally, I'd like to be able to enter this password only once and never again for the rest of my life.

**Improvement but not solution:**
I followed [this guide](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/faq/password-management) and I managed to make the password be remembered for some time. However, the maximum time you can set is only 99999 seconds.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way I can make GPG Suite remember my GPG password for a longer period of time than 99999 seconds?
2. Is there any other tool, other than GPG Suite, that can remember my GPG password forever or at least for a longer period of time? If yes, how can I save my password there and make it be remembered for as long as possible?

Comment: GPG uses a password to protect your key against unauthorized use. If you're sure you don't need it, you may want to remove the password. `gpg --edit-key ${fingerprint}`, then `passwd`